# How to disable Chrome Automation Extension via Selenium (Java)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver

I have a requirement to disable the "chrome automation extension" while running my selenium scripts.

Can someone suggest me an approach to disable this extension using Selenium.

[[image: Screenshot of Extensions settings in Chrome1]

Note: I tried already with

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
```

but in vain. So, please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Whenever we run our scripts, automatically this extension get enabled right while invoking the browser. You can see in the above screenshot a loader symbol displayed beside the Fav icon (Right to browser URL)

FYI:
Chrome Browser Version: Version 83.0.4103.116
Chrome driver version: 83.0.4103.39

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44884633/10858089 this may help you

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Or

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
ptions.addArguments("disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```